# Initial resistance / detent feeling in hydraulic brake

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

My brake has a up-front amount of pressure it needs before it will then engage. It feels like I'm actuating a clicky button and not a continuously moving brake. What could be causing this?

Comment: What is the Make/Model/age of brake? It might help get a better answer.

Comment: How much wear is there on the pads?  Disk brake pads don't seem to last as long as rim brake pads did.   Do the rear brakes feel the same as the fronts ?

Comment: I would almost go as far to say with hydraulic brakes, that wouldn't be to far from the norm.  To me they are very On/Off, like they are designed more for stopping rather than slowing down

Comment: Sounds as if a deep overhaul is required.

Comment: I am new to disc brakes and haven't ever serviced one. That said, I wonder if one or more of the pistons might be sticky? If it is that, it could be solved by taking the brake apart and cleaning the pistons with something like a toothbrush.

Comment: One possibility is that this is a Shimano brake with Servo-Wave and that the cam is gunked up. Not sure if the SRAM Swinglink equivalent has the same possible outcome, but I don’t see why not.